# SonarQube 4.3 in Java 8 not showing any Issues

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco

I'm running SonarQube 4.3 in Java 8 and it's not showing any numbers in Issues, Technical Debt and not showing any numbers in Blocker, Critical, etc. I've a gradle project with jacoco plugin and `gradle sonarRunner` runs fine and generates Unit Tests Coverage and Integration Tests Coverage. Also Java plugin is updated to 2.2.1. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on the [Requirements](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Requirements) page, Java 8 as a runtime is not fully supported yet, so that might explain some issues you encounter.

You should try to use Java 7 to see if the problem comes from the runtime or from some configuration issues.